# If you leave a job and your VACA-Prorota is 4.0 days

Tags: salary, vacation

Do I get paid for the vacation time I accumulated on my last pay check?

Comment: This sounds like something that is going to vary with every company's policy. You are best off asking your HR.

Comment: It is for my daughter worked a union job in California. Thank you.

Comment: Then your daughter is best off asking her union rep.

Answer (score 2):

It varies state by state, but in California, vacation pay is considered earned compensation, and will be cashed out to you when you separate from your employer.

For clarity, sick pay is is not considered earned compensation and there is no legal requirement for the employer to pay for sick hours.